# How do we pass the include Path?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, include

I created a "build" directory and ran `cmake ..` to run the ViennaTS software. It worked, but when I ran `make`, I got the following error.

```
Username@DESKTOP-DMU7A5N:~/ViennaTS/build$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/viennats.cpp.o
In file included from /home/Username/ViennaTS/src/viennats.cpp:61:
/home/Username/ViennaTS/viennats/Parameters.h:35:10: fatal error: sprng/sprng.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include "sprng/sprng.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/build.make:76: src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/viennats.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:125: src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I understand that the file sprng.h in the sprng directory is missing, but the file sprng/sprng.h does not exist in the SPRNG directory. The file sprng.h exists in the following Path.

```
/home/Username/sprng/SRC
/home/Username/sprng/include
```

In this case, should I modify `#include "sprng/sprng.h"` or should I modify the includePath `${workspaceFolder}/**`? I'm at a loss, so please help me if you know more.
The include portion of the code in `Parameters.h` is as follows.

```
#ifndef DEF_PARAMETERS
#define DEF_PARAMETERS

/* =========================================================================
   Copyright (c)    2008-2015, Institute for Microelectronics, TU Wien.
                            -----------------
                 ViennaTS - The Vienna Topography Simulator
                            -----------------
   Contact:         viennats@iue.tuwien.ac.at
   License:         MIT (X11), see file LICENSE in the base directory
============================================================================= */


#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_clear_actor.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_push_back_actor.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_increment_actor.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_decrement_actor.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_assign_actor.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_if.hpp>

#include "Partition/Partition.h"

#include "boundaries.h"

#include "message.h"

#include "parser_actors.h"

#include "sprng/sprng.h"

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
```

`CMakeList.txt` is the following:

```
# Required CMake Version
###############
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
#cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

# Project setup
###############
PROJECT(ViennaLS)

set(VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(VERSION_PATCH 0)
set(VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH})

# Default build type
##############
IF (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
ENDIF()

# Default compile options
#################
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O3 -g")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 ")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-O0 -g")


# Specify general include directory
################
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(".")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viennats/)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viennats/LSlib/)

# Specify that the output executable is placed in the root build directory
################
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})


# Find prerequisites
####################

# Look for additiona CMake modules in the cmake subdirectory ..
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# OpenMP ..
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP REQUIRED)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Boost ..
SET(BOOST_MIN_VERSION 1.46.0)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# SPRNG ..
FIND_PACKAGE(SPRNG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
SET(LIBRARIES ${LIBRARIES} ${SPRNG_LIBRARY})

# HDF5
FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX)
IF(HDF5_FOUND)
  IF(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_HDF5)
    add_definitions(${HDF5_DEFINITIONS})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(LIBRARIES ${LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
  ELSE(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Missing HDF5 C++ library")
  ENDIF(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
ELSE(HDF5_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Missing HDF5 library: ViennaTS will be built without TDR file support")
ENDIF(HDF5_FOUND)

# Subdirectories
################
add_subdirectory(src)

# Add visibility of headers
# Necessary for Qt-Creator usage.
################
file( GLOB_RECURSE MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE_SRC *.hpp *.h)
add_custom_target( MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE SOURCES ${MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE_SRC} )
```

`cmake ..` generated the following Makefile.

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.22

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/ishitanaken23/ViennaTS

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/ishitanaken23/ViennaTS/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/ishitanaken23/ViennaTS/build/CMakeFiles /home/ishitanaken23/ViennaTS/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/ishitanaken23/ViennaTS/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE

# Build rule for target.
MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE
.PHONY : MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE

# fast build rule for target.
MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE.dir/build
.PHONY : MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named viennats

# Build rule for target.
viennats: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 viennats
.PHONY : viennats

# fast build rule for target.
viennats/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/viennats.dir/build
.PHONY : viennats/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... MAKE_HEADERS_VISIBLE"
    @echo "... viennats"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: "or should I modify the includePath ${workspaceFolder}/** ?" Where are you setting thus include path? The includePath in `c_cpp_properties.json` has nothing to do with building your code in VSCode. It's only for the Intellisense mode.

Comment: We probably need to see the `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @drescherjm, The includePath are from the distribution, so they are all default settings.
I put CMakeCache. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I suspect the problem happened on this line: `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR})` I expect that `SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR` was empty or not correct. You can check by putting a `message( FATAL_ERROR SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR="${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR}")`  after that line and looking at the error message generated to see of it has SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/Username/sprng/include

Comment: @drescherjm, According to CMakeCache, `SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/Username/sprng/include.`

Comment: Does the file  `/home/Username/sprng/include/sprng/sprng.h` exist? or is it `/home/Username/sprng/include/sprng.h`

Comment: @drescherjm, The latter. `home/Username/sprng/include/sprng.h`

Comment: You would temporarily add that line to the CMakeLists.txt after `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Comment: Did you try to change `#include "sprng/sprng.h"` to `#include "sprng.h"`  This may not work if `sprng.h` includes  any headers. in that folder.

Comment: @drescherjm, I did "You would temporarily add that line to the CMakeLists.txt after INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR})".
I got `SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR="/home/Username/sprng/include"`

Comment: Thanks. Now remove that line. This is one method I use to debug problems with `CMakeLists.txt` when I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Try using `#include "sprng.h"` instead of `#include "sprng/sprng.h"` Your problem seems to be a change in the folder structure since the documentation that you are using was produced.

Comment: @drescherjm, I changed `sprng/sprng.h` to `sprng.h` and I can resolve the error. However, another error occured. `not declared in this scope.`

Comment: I think your versions of one or more of the dependencies is newer than this few years old code expects. I see the following message "Unfortunately, ViennaTS is no longer being supported. I would redirect you to our ViennaPS tool (https://github.com/ViennaTools/ViennaPS), which has more features than ViennaTS and works on Linux, MacOS, and Windows." in the issues page for ViennaTS https://github.com/viennats/viennats-dev/issues/31#issuecomment-1597098359

Comment: Did you build sprng or are you trying to use its source?  Its build and install scripts probably place sprng/sprng.h in your system include directory (as well as its compiled library in your system lib directory).  See the instructions on its [quick-start page](http://www.sprng.org/Version5.0/quick-start.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what editor/environment are you using? This sometimes makes a difference.

Never modify the includes directives. If it should be `"sprng/sprng.h"` then it needs to remain so. Trying to modify the directive will fail immediately as soon as other files are included within the file `"sprng/sprng.h"`.

You need to post either your `CMakeList.txt` or your `Makefile`.

But just thinking ahead: if you are working with a makefile and compiling with `gcc` then you can append `-I/home/Username/sprng/SRC -I/home/Username/sprng/SRC` to the build command. For example:

```
file.o : file.cpp
    g++ ... -I/home/Username/sprng/SRC -I/home/Username/sprng/SRC
```

Edit:
Why do your calls to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...)` not include the two directories you list above? What does the resultant `Makefile` look like?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu by WSL2.

Comment: Is ${SPRNG_INCLUDE_DIR} ever defined?

Comment: CMakeList.txt and Makefile are upper on the Website.